# Read the data between the HTML tags, HTML parser

Tags: html, html-parsing

Need the procedure to read the tag from the HTML and fetch the dynamic value that is generated from the webpage and convert to JSON form.
Webpage has table. Read the table header and fetch the data that is populated to the table.
In other words parse the HTML from browser, fetch value and convert to the JSON. Is the 1) Restful Webservices , the solution ? or  2) combine the program of the HTML parser and string regex?

Read the this  Transaction Name from HTML file
and provide the output as Transaction Name in a json format

Answer (score 0):

for this tag

```
<td id="LraTransaction Name" class="table_header" vAlign="top">
 <span class="Verdana2">Transaction Name</span>
</td>
```

transaction 001
 Average
         32.893
need to fetch the Transaction Name and the dynamic values from the table.

Output should display

|Transaction   |      Average|
|Transaction001  |   32.893|
|Transaction002   |   53.982|

Also convert to json